# VB6 remove text from string until character

Tags: vb6

I'm making a program in VB6 for sorting my files. With a few buttons I can choose a category. A lot of these files have a number in front of the filename

Example: `1111-FILENAME` or `12-FILENAME`

I have been trying to use the split function:

```
filename.Text = Split(filename.Text, "-")(1)
```

But that doesn't work if there are more `-` characters in the filename. It should start from the left looking at a `-`, and then stop and delete those characters including `-`. So I only have `FILENAME` left.

Comment: I believe that you were saying that your filename was always immediately preceded by a dash, as in your two examples, but that the waste characters in front of the filename sometimes had another dash in them.  However, Mark has edited your post to suggest that you may have dashes in your filename as well, presumably because my solution doesn't account for this.  Please clarify whether or not you need to account for dashes in your filename.

Comment: @BobRodes I've looked at my edit, and it seems the more reasonable interpretation. On a QWERTY keyboard, the 'f' and 'r' keys are so near, that this is a very common typo. Also, *Example: 1111-FILENAME of 12-FILENAME* looked like 2 items, not one. Anyway, as you say, it's user3586368 responsibility to confirm or deny :-)

Answer (score 2):

Split() is not very helpful in this situation. I suppose you could subsequently use Join() to rejoin the parts of the array returned by Split() that you are interested in. But it would be more efficient to find the *first* dash, and then rip out the strings on either side of the dash. The following function could be used to do this:

```
Function GetNumberAndFileNameFromValue(ByRef in_sValue As String, ByRef out_sNumber As String, ByRef out_sFileName As String) As Boolean

    Dim lLastDash   As Long

    lLastDash = InStr(1, in_sValue, "-")
    If lLastDash > 0 Then
        out_sNumber = Left$(in_sValue, lLastDash - 1)
        out_sFileName = Mid$(in_sValue, lLastDash + 1)
        GetNumberAndFileNameFromValue = True
    Else
        GetNumberAndFileNameFromValue = False
    End If

End Sub
```

This generic function will allow you to get both values, if you want. If you just want the filename, you can create another wrapper:

```
Function GetFileNameFromValue(ByRef in_sValue As String) As String
    GetNumberAndFileNameFromValue in_sValue, vbNullString, GetFileNameFromValue
End Function
```

e.g.

```
Debug.Print GetFileNameFromValue("1111-FILENAME-WITH-LOTS-OF-DASHES")
```

Comment: It would be more efficient if we were to assume that the OP is asking about multiple dashes in the filename, and not in the string preceding it.  A closer look at your solution shows that it doesn't take that possibility into account, whereas mine doesn't take the possibility that there are dashes in the filename into account.  You've edited his requirements to state your interpretation at the expense of mine, but really neither of us know what the OP wants.  We'll see what he has to say if he responds to my request for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler solution than Mark's (sorry Mark, yours works and does more than this, but still, this does what the OP asked for):

```
example = "1321-3435-MYFILENAME.EXT"
Debug.Print Right(example, Len(example) - InStrRev("example", "-"))
```

will return "MYFILENAME.EXT".

I'll break it down.  Len(string) returns the length of string, in this case 24.  InStrRev(string, charmatch) returns the position (starting from the left, which can be confusing) of the first charmatch it finds in string, starting from the right.  In this case that is 10.  Right(string, x) takes the rightmost x characters of a string.  Using the Right function with the numbers plugged in for the other functions will make the solution more obvious:

```
Right("1321-3435-MYFILENAME.EXT", 24-10)
```

This will return "MYFILENAME.EXT" as well.

**[Edit]**

Mark's interpretation of the OP's requirements differs from mine.  (The requirements as now stated differ from the OP's original; Mark has edited them to fit his interpretation.  We shall see if the OP clarifies.)  I understood that he wanted to account for multiple dashes in the *string preceding* the filename, and Mark understood that he wanted to account for multiple dashes *in* the filename.

Now, even if we take Mark's interpretation as correct, we can still simplify his solution in the same way, by using InStr instead of InStrRev:

```
example = "1321-MY-FILE-NAME.EXT"
Debug.Print Right(example, Len(example) - InStr("example", "-"))
```

This will return "MY-FILE-NAME.EXT".

Essentially, my first code example returns all characters to the right of the rightmost dash in the string.  Substituting InStr will return all the characters to the right of the leftmost dash in the string.

Comment: Counter-example: "24323-A-FILENAME-WITH-OTHER-DASHES.EXT"

Comment: Well, sure, now that you've edited the OP's post to change his requirements in such a way as to make my solution unworkable.  Perhaps he failed to mention that he needs to account for dashes in his filename.  We'll see...

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the misunderstanding! :D

i wanted to keep "-" in "MY-FILE-NAME". only remove the leading characters if any.

so "1321-MY-FILE-NAME.EXT" should be: "MY-FILE-NAME.EXT".
i don't have files with: "1321-1234-MY-FILE-NAME.EXT". so thats not a problem.

Thank you both for helping. I have something to work with now and can continue. Always find it difficult to manipulate strings. But i'm learning.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion string manipulation should **always, always, ALWAYS** be done with regular expressions. they are easy to create, easy to read (yes you are right, just until some complexity is reached *g*)

Try something like:

```
Dim myRegExp As RegExp
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Dim myMatch As Match

Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
myRegExp.Global = True
myRegExp.Pattern = "^(?<numbers>(\d+-)+).+$"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(subjectString)

For Each myMatch in myMatches
  MsgBox(myMatch.Value)
Next
```

Explanation of the regex can be see under: http://regex101.com/

i think i remember vb6 having problems with named capturing groups so you probably have to use "**^(?:(\d+-)+).+$**" which is just a capturing group, so you can access the result by index in **myMatch.Groups[0].Value** or something like that.

Hope this helps to get some new ideas of how to work with strings in vb6 or in general.

always use regex :)

greetings
SLimke